# Django Time_Zone not saving correct values

Tags: python, django

I have the following settings in my `settings.py` regarding Time zones.

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_TZ = True
```

Using a datetime field, say I save a particular time as

```
Date: 2015-04-01
Time: 22:00:00
```

it still gets stored as `2015-04-01 16:30:00` in my database which on querying returns `04:30 PM 01/04/2015` but in admin still shows

```
Date: 2015-04-01
Time: 22:00:00
```

How do I fix this error? Is there a setting that I'm missing in `settings.py`?

Comment: @Selcuk Windows 8.1 and using MySQL as the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Windows, you have to actually change the operating system timezone to be able to reliably work:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE

> Note
>
> Django cannot reliably use alternate time zones in a Windows environment. If you’re running Django on Windows, TIME_ZONE must be set to match the system time zone.

Comment: When you set `TIME_ZONE=None` it will use the system (Windows') timezone settings.

Comment: @JasonArg123 Yes, lots have changed since 2015 and Django 1.7. See [the latest documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TIME_ZONE). `None` is not a valid option anymore.